# cq:DialogMode "floating" change dialog title

Tags: adobe, aem

So I have a component in AEM that has an edit bar. Dialog mode of this bar is set to floating, and I need to change the title of the dialog. I have read all the docs I could find and have tried changing the dialog title as it would normally be done, but all that ever shows up is the default "Edit Component" title.

Can this be changed? And if so, how?

Edit: After removing the xtype as suggested, I was able to get the titles to show. This however caused another problem for my dialog that had an xtype of tabpanel. Those components now only have the first tab defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue occurs mostly because, the `xtype` for the `cq:dialog` node would be set to something else (most probably panel or tabpanel) instead of `dialog`.

Check for the same, and in case it has been set, change the xtype to `dialog` or remove the xtype altogether in order to view the title in the dialog's edit mode.

Comment: I did check the xtype for the dialog and it was set to tabpanel. Removing the xtype fixed the problem. Thanks so much!

Comment: I advise to always have a complete structure with dialog -> tabpanel -> panel hierarchy. It happened to me so many times that I needed to add them afterwards because the author wanted to have a wider dialog and you can only set this on dialog level.

Comment: It seems to me that the cq:EditConfig assumes that any cq:dialog is of xtype dialog and manually adding this confuses the situation. I wish this wasn't so, and seems to actually be a bug, but removing the xtype is the only thing that allowed it to work. The node of type cq:dialog still exists and allows the definition of size.